# Compare years and month with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var onemonth = 3;
var oneyear = 2005;
var twomonth = 10;
var twoyear = 2000;
```

How can i split this and compare?
In this example is:

```
var firstdate = onemonth + oneyear;
var seconddate = twomonth + twoyear;

if(firstdate < seconddate){
 alert('error');
}
```

How is the best method for compare two date if i have only month and year?

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/26zms/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using the native Date object like this?

```
if (new Date(oneyear, onemonth) < new Date(twoyear, twomonth)){
  alert('error');
}else{
  alert('ok');
}
```

With your variables it will yield "ok".

Comment: Usually you have to substract 1 from `onemonth` and `twomonth`. Months to the Date object are zero-based. So, if you pass `12`, the year will increase by one, and the month is January. **For this case**, it doesn't matter because both `Date` objects are forwarded one month. (If you didn't understand the previous line: `3 < 10` is equivalent to `3-1 < 10-1`).

Comment: You're right in both points! As long as `new Date(2011, 12)` is equivalent to `new Date(2012, 0)` the comparison is safe.

Answer (score 2):

Make then proper dates;

```
var firstdate =  new Date(oneyear, onemonth - 1, 1); 
var seconddate = new Date(twoyear, twomonth - 1, 1);
```

Then the comparison is valid (as opposed to comparing arbitrarily created integers)

Answer (score 1):

acording to me append zero and than concate string

```
var onemonth = 3; 
if(onemonth < 10)
 onemonth = "0" + onemonth;
var oneyear = 2005; 
var oneyearmonth = oneyear + onemonth; // 200503
var twomonth = 10; 
if(twomonth < 10)
 twomonth = "0" + twomonth ;
var twoyear = 2000;
var twoyearmonth = twoyear + twomonth ; //200010
if(oneyearmonth < twoyearmonth)
{
   alert("one month and year leass than tow month and year");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use the `Date` object for this case. Simple math is sufficient:

- Divide the month by twelve.
- Add this value to the year.
- Do the same for the other date(s), and compare the values:

Code:

```
var onemonth = 3;
var oneyear = 2005;
var twomonth = 10;
var twoyear = 2000;

var year1 = oneyear + onemonth / 12;
var year2 = twoyear + twomonth / 12;
if (year1 < year2) {
    // error?
}
```