# Validate Months

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I validate a month using Start Date and End Date, and based on that want to show message.
e.g If Start Date and End Date is **greater** than **12 Months** then show Message "Selected months are over 12 months" else do something else....

The values that I have on **start Date** and **End Date** is **1** until **12** that represent **January** until **December**

Start date and End date is a calendar control which I have got the "Code = 1 and Description = January" that is what I save on my database. so on the screen it will show start date = 2021-01-01 and End date = 2022-03-01 meaning its now 15Months

this is what I have done so far, Please do assist if you can.

```
 if ($("#startDate").val() + $("#EndDate").val() > 12) {
    $("#MonthErrorMessage").html("Selected months are over 12 months");
    $("#MonthErrorMessage").show();
    isValid = false;
} else{
    $('#MonthErrorMessage').hide();
}
```

Comment: Please give a number of examples of what data can be returned by `$("#startDate").val()` and also by `$("#endDate").val()`.

Comment: How can someone specify 13 months or more if they can only choose between 1 and 12?

Comment: @SalmanA maybe its a range of 2 + years?

Comment: @SalmanA and PeterB Start date and End date is a calendar control which I have got the "Code = 1 and Description = January" that is what I save on my database. so on the screen it will show start date = 2021-01-01 and End date = 2022-03-01 meaning its now 15Months

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare years and month with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380080/compare-years-and-month-with-jquery)